# How to read a a SQL Server Table as a Matrix in R

Tags: sql-server, r, matrix

I have a table in SQL Server that looks like that:

```
ID    ID1    ID2
1      4      7
2      2      6
```

I create that table using `PIVOT` in SQL Server

Now, I want to manipulate that Matrix in R so I have this:

`library(RODBC)
ch <- odbcDriverConnect("driver=SQL Server; server=DT12345\\SQLEXPRESS; database=MyDatabase; trusted_connection=true")
res <- sqlFetch(ch, "CorrTable")
dat <- data.matrix(res)
solve(dat)`

Which gives me the following error because data.matrix includes the first column and/or the headers in the Matrix:

`Error in solve.default(dat) : 'a' (2 x 3) must be square`

Comment: Remove your first column ? `dat <-dat[,-1]` But note, your data is 2x3

Comment: @Cedric Because it's a Matrix in pivot table, so removing the first column and the Headers should leave 2X2 Matrix. I tried `dat <-dat[,-1]` but that removes the last column instead of the first column. I also need to remove the headers

Comment: @Cedric, It works, I had a typo. It appears that Solve(dat) take in account the headers